# What is array_slice()?

Tags: php, arrays

## update

I'm new to PHP development: I looked on the PHP website for a function - `array_slice`. I read and looked at the example but I don't understand it. Can someone explain this in clear words for me?

I think it works as follow?

```
$example = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$offset = 2;
$length = 5;
$newArray = array_slice($example, offset, length);

the result of $newArray is: $newArray(3,4,5,6,7);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but it looks like e.g. array_slice($arr,3) returns another array which contains the elements of $arr starting at 3 (i.e. missing out elements 0, 1 and 2). So it's a bit like the substr function which is used with strings.

Comment: Here to go http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: It's my example correct?

Comment: Just run the code and you'll see whether your assumption is correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [stefgosselin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161627/1494454) that has some mistakes: Lets start with his array:

```
$input = array(1,2,3);
```

This contains:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> int(1)
    [1]=> int(2)
    [2]=> int(3)
}
```

Then you do [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
var_dump(array_slice($input, 1));
```

The function will return the values after the first element (thats what the second argument, the offset means). But notice the keys!

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> int(2)
    [1]=> int(3)
}
```

Keep in mind that keys aren't preserved, until you pass `true` for the fourth `preserve_keys` parameter. Also because there is another `length` parameter before this, you have to pass `NULL` if you want to return everything after the offset, but with the keys preserved.

```
var_dump(array_slice($input, 1, NULL, true));
```

That will return what stefgosselin (incorrectly) wrote initially.

```
array(2) {
    [1]=> int(2)
    [2]=> int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function returns a subset of the array. To understand the example on the man page you have to understand array keys start at 0, ie

```
 $array_slice = $array(1,2,3);
```

The above contains this:

```
$array[0] = 1,
$array[1] = 2,
$array[2] = 3
```

So, `array_slice(1)` of `$array_sliced` would return:

```
$arraysliced = array_slice($array_slice, 1);
$arraysliced[1] = 2;
$arraysliced[2] = 3;
```

Comment: There are many mistakes in this answer. The code is mixed with comments. Thats not how you define an array. But the biggest mistake is that you wrote the sliced array's keys incorrectly. Also slicing a `1` doesn't really makes sense. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23542155) for the fixed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the part of your input array that starts at your defined offset, of the your defined length.

Think of it this way:

```
$output = array();
for ($i = 0; $i++; $i < count($input)) {
  if ($i < $start)
    continue;
  if ($i > $start + $length)
    break;
  $output[] = $input[$i];
}
```

Comment: Any example with a length. The step by step code was written before you posted your example. Follow it step by step and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Basically its an skip and take operation. Skip meaning to jump to that element. Take meaning how many.

Comment: you probably spun his head on his neck once again after the php manual... the poor guy might not understand your terse language :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built - in function, array_slice() , that you can use to extract a range of elements from an
array. To use it, pass it the array to extract the slice from, followed by the position of the first element in
the range (counting from zero), followed by the number of elements to extract. The function returns a new
array containing copies of the elements you extracted (it doesn ’ t touch the original array). For example:

```
$authors = array( “Steinbeck”,
“Kafka”, “Tolkien”, “Dickens” );
$authorsSlice = array_slice(
$authors, 1, 2 ); // Displays “Array
( [0] = > Kafka [1] = > Tolkien )”
print_r( $authorsSlice );
```

By the way, if you leave out the third argument to array_slice() , the function extracts all elements
from the start position to the end of the array:

```
$authors = array( “Steinbeck”, “Kafka”, “Tolkien”, “Dickens” );
$authorsSlice = array_slice( $authors, 1 );
// Displays “Array ( [0] = > Kafka [1] = > Tolkien [2] = > Dickens )”;
print_r( $authorsSlice );
```

Earlier you learned that array_slice() doesn ’ t preserve the indices of elements taken from an indexed
array. If you want to preserve the indices, you can pass a fourth argument, true , to array_slice() :

```
$authors = array( “Steinbeck”, “Kafka”, “Tolkien”, “Dickens” );
// Displays “Array ( [0] = > Tolkien [1] = > Dickens )”;
print_r( array_slice( $authors, 2, 2 ) );
// Displays “Array ( [2] = > Tolkien [3] = > Dickens )”;
print_r( array_slice( $authors, 2, 2, true ) );
```