# pull only 20 latest photos from the folder

Tags: php

so I have this code

```
     <?php 

      $images = glob("slike/*.*");

      sort($images);

      foreach ($images as $img) {

        echo '<div class="image_wrapper"><img src="'.$img.'"></div>';

      }

    ?>
```

and it's working great but I want to pull **only 20 latest photos** and not all of them since there is over one hundred.

How can I do this?
Also is there a way to show it like from 5th to 25th?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? I think if you look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) you might find examples that help you.

Comment: put it inside a loop and increase any variable by 1 every time the loop runs

Comment: Latest as in "last modification time of file"?

Comment: I tired using array_slice() but it did not work-

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález why is this marked as duplicate when I didn't get answer on how to pull **only 20** images and not all of them

Comment: Because your code does not even attempt to grab the file modification time, which is the hard part? If all you need is to crop an array, `array_slice()` does work.

Comment: [What is array_slice()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161592/what-is-array-slice) / [array_slice but for images php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727672/array-slice-but-for-images-php/46727827)

Comment: Thanks, found a way by using break;